# Memory usage in BufferAttribute

Tags: three.js

*// it's a newbie question, don't have much experience with WebGL*

I'm trying to optimize memory usage (mostly to allow to use our site with mobile devices).

Our meshes are using BufferGeometry with several BufferAttribute instances (vertices, normals, colors, etc), and as I see under IE DevTools each BufferAttribute contains two major memory consuming fields:

- **array** - data for the given buffer attribute.
- **buffer** - WebGLBuffer, which contains copied data from the **array** field.

As I understand - in some situations the **buffer** gets recreated, and at that point the **array** data will be reused. But if all geometry is readonly - would it be safe to clean up **array** to save memory? Or are there other situations when WebGL buffer has to be recreated (say - user switched to another tab in browser, and all WebGL stuff should be recreated on return)?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you need to keep the CPU data around in case the WebGL context is lost. In that case the GL objects all have to recreated from the CPU data.